# how to find primitive roots of a number

Tags: c, malloc

This is the code i was trying to compile for finding primitive root...but it gives me the error as.

```
int isPrimitive (int q, int a) {
int i,z;
double k,s;

s=1;
i=0;

double *factors=malloc(sizeof(double)*q-2);    

while (s>0 && i<q-2) {
    k=pow(a,i);
    s=k-(q*floor(k/q));
    for (z=0;z<(sizeof(*factors)/sizeof(factors[0]));z++) {
        if (factors[z]==s) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    factors[i]=s;
    i++;
}
```

here in the line `double *factors=malloc(sizeof(double)*q-2);`
// error invalid conversion from void* to double* comes.

Comment: What compiler are you using? (Also, why `sizeof(double)*q-2`? Is that mean to be `sizeof(double)*(q-2)`?)

Comment: Do you compile it with a C or C++ compiler? The error message indicates the latter.

Comment: You need to cast the `void*` that `malloc()` returns, as in: `double *factors = (double*)malloc(...);` ... well, or use a C compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly using a C++ compiler on C code. In C `void*` can be converted to any pointer type without a cast, while this is not true in C++, hence the error message. There are basically two solutions: use a C compiler (e.g. `gcc` rather than `g++`), or cast the result of malloc.

The latter can be done by:

```
double *factors = static_cast<double*> (malloc(sizeof(double)*(q-2)));
```

But if you are actually writing C++, then using the [`new []`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29) syntax is better:

```
double *factors = new double [q-2];
```

(Note that this requires using `delete[] factors` instead of `free(factors)`)